# How to set animation progress with anime.js/velocity.js/etc.?

Tags: javascript, animation, velocity.js, anime.js

I have animation like this (`anime.js` example):

```
anime({
  targets: '.selector',
  opacity: 0.5,
  translateX: 200,
  duration: 1,
});
```

Then i need to set progress of this animation depending on page scroll position (or any js library for scrolling).

For example:

- on 20% of scroll have to be set as
  `"opacity:0.9;transform:translateX(40px);"`
- on 50% of scroll -
  `"opacity:0.75;transform:translateX(100px);"`
- etc.

I'd like to avoid calculating every value of animation by myself.

Is there build-in tools in `anime.js`/`velocity.js` or libraries like them?

`gsap.js` has `.progress()` method that works as i need, but i'd like to find lighter library for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, anime.js has progress seeking functions. The one you're looking for is [seek()](https://animejs.com/documentation/#seekAnim). It's used like this:

```
var animation = anime({
  targets: '.selector',
  opacity: 0.5,
  translateX: 200,
  duration: 1,
});
animation.seek(0.2 * animation.duration);
animation.seek(0.5 * animation.duration);
```

It's done in milliseconds, so you have to multiply by the duration of the animation. But for your purposes, just plug in your scroll progress within a scroll event handler and it'd all work nicely.

```
animation.seek(scrollProgress * animation.duration);
```